# Need Help taking User Input

Tags: c#, type-conversion, user-input

I am trying to create a program that asks a user what their height is and how any steps they have taken and covert that into miles. I am having trouble getting the program to even ask the user the questions and help would be appreciated. Here is the Code I have so far.

```
float Height;
float Steps;
float CON_FAC;
float FEET_IN_Mile;
float strideLength;
float averageStride;
float feetWalked; 
float milesWalked;

Console.Write("Input height(inches): ");
Height = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Input Steps(today):");
Steps = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());

CON_FAC = .413F; 
FEET_IN_Mile = 5280;
strideLength = Height * CON_FAC;
averageStride = strideLength / 12;
feetWalked = averageStride * Steps;
milesWalked = feetWalked / FEET_IN_Mile;
Console.WriteLine($"You walked {milesWalked} miles");
```

Comment: "*I am having trouble getting the program to even ask the user the questions*" - what's the problem, are you getting an exception?

Comment: You'll be happier with `float.TryParse`. It won't throw an exception when your users mistype a number

Answer (score 0):

Use float.TryParse or float.Parse

```
float Height;
float Steps;
float CON_FAC;
float FEET_IN_Mile;
float strideLength;
float averageStride;
float feetWalked; 
float milesWalked;

Console.Write("Input height(inches): ");
Height = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Input Steps(today):");
Steps = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

CON_FAC = .413F; 
FEET_IN_Mile = 5280;
strideLength = Height * CON_FAC;
averageStride = strideLength / 12;
feetWalked = averageStride * Steps;
milesWalked = feetWalked / FEET_IN_Mile;
Console.WriteLine("You walked " + milesWalked + " miles");
```

use this or check if value is float

```
float Height;
float Steps;
float CON_FAC;
float FEET_IN_Mile;
float strideLength;
float averageStride;
float feetWalked; 
float milesWalked;

incagain:
Console.Write("Input height(inches): ");
if(float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out Height))
{

}
else
{
    goto incagain;
}
todayagain:
Console.Write("Input Steps(today):");
if(float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out Steps))
{

}
else
{
    goto todayagain;
}

CON_FAC = .413F; 
FEET_IN_Mile = 5280;
strideLength = Height * CON_FAC;
averageStride = strideLength / 12;
feetWalked = averageStride * Steps;
milesWalked = feetWalked / FEET_IN_Mile;
Console.WriteLine("You walked " + milesWalked + " miles");
```